# How to put a comment in a SQL query of JSON items from Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: sql, azure

For an existing Azure Cosmos DB, I am testing SQL queries following [this guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started#query-the-json-items). I would like to insert comments in my query, but the following fails,

```
SELECT * FROM c /* Example comment */
```

While this works fine,

```
SELECT * FROM c
```

What is the format for inserting a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM c -- Example comment`

Comment: I couldn't find this in any documentation. If you happen to know where this is documented (because there's likely other useful stuff there), please let me know.

Comment: google(SQL comment)

Comment: That is how I found the /* Comment */ format in my example, but it didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: There appears to be differences between SQL implementations, some not having an option or keyword, others requiring a slightly different syntax - the comment might be an example, showing up like this.